# How to combine values from multiple rows into a single row with a comma separator

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vba

I have an Excel file that lists product SKUs in one culumn and product image URLs in a another column. My problem is that the file has multiple rows for the same product...

[image: http://i.imgur.com/mVn1EYa.jpg]

...when the CMS I use on my shop can only read imports like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/nQNCjci.jpg]

I would do it manually but there are hundreds of products, each with multiple image links. Basically, I need to have only one SKU001 (SKU002, SKU003, etc.) and merge its corresponding B column cells into one cell with all values separated by a comma. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say we have data in *Sheet1*.  The SKUs are in column **A** and **B** can contain any data.  The SKUs are sorted:

[image]

The following macro will produce re-organized data in *Sheet2*:

```
Sub ReOrganizer()
   Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
   Dim N As Long, i As Long, K As Long
   Dim v1 As String, v2 As String
   Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
   Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
   K = 1
   N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   v1 = s1.Cells(2, 1).Value
   v2 = s1.Cells(2, 2).Value

   For i = 3 To N
      vn1 = s1.Cells(i, 1).Value
      vn2 = s1.Cells(i, 2).Value
      If vn1 = v1 Then
         v2 = v2 & "," & vn2
      Else
         s2.Cells(K, 1) = v1
         s2.Cells(K, 2) = v2
         v1 = vn1
         v2 = vn2
         K = K + 1
      End If
   Next i

   s2.Cells(K, 1) = v1
   s2.Cells(K, 2) = v2

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly when I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Think I have a no macro solution

[image: raw]

Which filters to
[image: filtered]

in C2 type =IF(A2=A1,C1&","&B2,B2)

Then in D2 type =COUNTIF(C3,B3)

And fill down to one row below your table

The C col concatenates with the string above if the same product, or starts a new chain if a new product

The D col finds the end of a chain (by checking if the row below is a new chain)

Please try this and tell me if it works :)

Comment: in case I wasn't clear, use autofilter on col D and show only "1", then you can copy that to wherever or export to csv etc.

Comment: I think your general approach is very good if macro are not allowed *(+1)*

Comment: Thanks. The macro solution isn't noob-friendly: it converted IDs with an `E` in them to scientific notation  (e.g., `25E10` -> `250000000000`). It also dropped preceding `0`'s. (e.g., `0001` -> `1`). (Converting the columns to "Text" or "General" did not rectify this.) I also did not know how to bring over additional columns from the old sheet into the new one (despite trying what I thought would work).

Comment: Good to know, glad this random thing from 6 years ago helped someone :)